# How do I copy and replace a file with Kotlin gradle after the build is completed?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build

I have gotten it to work with intellij task activation, however this doesn't seem to apply to others code when they pull from git. I basically want to do this but in code.

[rad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oMnt.png)

```
tasks.register<Copy>("copyReport") {
from(file("$projectDir/logiceditor-ui/build/distributions/logiceditor-ui.js"))
into(file("$projectDir/logiceditor-service/src/main/resources/static"))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the task `assemble`(which compiles and assembles your code) depend on your task.

Comment: What would be the syntax for that? Adding dependsOn("assemble") seems to have no effect